# Windows 10 Professional with TeamGroup SSD 256 GB, 4 TB HDD from Seagate

Tags: windows, hard-drive, ssd, permissions, icacls

My computer is having a serious problem since it's run out of disk space. I keep trying to fix it by moving everything over to my 4TB HDD but it's not letting me move files and my computer can't startup in anything other than recovery mode. Through command prompt I've tried moving the files but it's telling me I don't have permission. I ran the icacls command to grant myself permission using C:\> icacls Battle.net /grant Mike:F and it gives me the error "No mapping between account names and security IDs was done." And then it says that it failed. After looking this up I learned that I needed to make a new administrator account and when I try to do that it says "The user was successfully created but could not be added to the USERS local group. I can't even reinstall windows via cloud or locally because of the lack of space. What should I do to get space back on my C: drive if I can't move anything change permissions or even add another user. My PC will not start up normally only into repair mode. Any ideas?

Comment: I continue to wonder why people buy computers with disks that are too small.  Do a fresh install of Windows on the 4 TB drive and make it Drive C:

Comment: Your SSD might have failed. Buy a new one, install Windows to it (or clone your current install) and then see what can be recovered from the old one.

Comment: If the boot up problem is actually causes by no free space, run Ubuntu live and move some non-essential files from your c:\ drive to 4TB drive. But being unable to move anything around sounds like a bigger problem. Again I point to Ubuntu live. There you can run fsck.ntfs on c:\ to identify errors. Can you run chkdsk when in recovery mode (and are you in start-up recovery mode or Windows safe mode)?